# Rename [ruby2.5] to [ruby-2.5]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Each Ruby language version has a tag, for example [ruby-2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-2.3), [ruby-2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-2.4) etc. However, the tag for Ruby 2.5 is [ruby2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby2.5), without the dash, making it inconsistent with the other tags.

There are only four questions with the [ruby2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby2.5) tag, so renaming them manually shouldn't be too hard. I tried to do this myself, but I can't create [ruby-2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-2.5) because its name is too similar to the existing tag without the dash.

Comment: May I ask why this has been downvoted?

Comment: Maybe because a single user can correct the problem...

Comment: @Braiam I don't seem to be able to create the new tag though, because it's too similar to the old one. Am I missing something?

Comment: Remove the tag then create the tag.

Comment: @Braiam I'm embarrassed that I didn't think to do that; I'll get on it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed the [ruby2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby2.5) tag from all four questions, waited for the automatic cleanup script to delete it, and then added the [ruby-2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-2.5) tag to those questions.

I didn't realise this would be so easy for one user to do; sorry for hassling Meta with it.

Comment: I'm curious, what's so special about Ruby 2.5 that it needs a dedicated tag?

Comment: @Gimby the same as ruby-2.3 and ruby-2.4... a different version number.

Comment: so.... how often does the automatic cleanup script run?  I might have just one the same thing with a new python tag.....